# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_close()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning about MySQL prepare statement and when I run the following code, I get the PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_close(). The output is correct and I just can't figure out why such an error occurs.
Thanks for your time!

```php
$conn3 = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

$event_type = $jarray['event_type'];
$key = "submission";

$search = $conn3->prepare("SELECT * FROM metadb USE INDEX(field_id) WHERE event_type = ? AND event_field = ?");
$search->bind_param('ss', $event_type, $key); 
$search->execute();
$search->store_result();

echo $search->num_rows;

mysql_close($conn3);
```

Comment: It is highly likely that you do not need to close your connection. Remember that it will be closed automatically at the end of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$conn3->close();` instead of `mysql_close($conn3);`

You are using `mysqli` to open connection and then trying to close connection using `mysql`.

***Suggestion :*** You are mixing `mysqli`object oriented and procedural in your code I will suggest you to stick with one(preferably Object Oriented).
I will also suggest you to start using `PDO` instead of `mysqli`. [reason explained here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

For more detailed information about `mysqli` you can refer this [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

For more detailed information about `PDO` you can refer this [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).